# Data of Pokemon Go in Google account is gone

Tags: pokemon-go

I changed phone from an iPhone to a Samsung device. I reinstalled Pokemon Go and signed in with the same Google account, but it started a new trainer with zero Pokemon. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not sure that is a true duplicate of that specific question.

Comment: Do you still have the iPhone? Try logging in again from that phone. You can also try to login from a friends phone on your account to see if that works. Also bear in mind that on Android it will use the Google account which you have created/linked to the device.